# Rotating a Textured Sphere results in artifacts

Tags: opengl-es, glfw

I am able to texture a earthmap.bmp onto a sphere (using the GLFW framework). Using OPENGL ES 3.00 shaders. However when I rotate the sphere (via a keystroke ), I get artifacts.

EarthMap :[Earth Mapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYvQ3.jpg)

Earth Map with rotation

[Artifacts after rotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AuhM.jpg)

Could anyone tell me what the problem is ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it,
I needed to clear the depth buffer for every Frame update !

// Clear the screen
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);